# Linq To Twitter - Who's in this photo

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I have been playing with Linq to twitter for a while now. I have the code working fine to upload media, in my case I am uploading images. This will be automated and I get the people I tag from our list of followers.

What I want to do is to "tag" followers in my image upload. In twitter parlance it is known as - who is in this photo" In the normal browser you may add/tag ten people in the photo.

I cannot seem to find any overload in the LinkToTwitter functions. I suspect it may be the additional owners, but the description does not make sense to me.

I looked for overloads in the TweetAsync, but there does not seem to be anything there that I can use. I suspect that it will be a List that I will add to an overload, but which overload?

My code is as follows:

```
static async Task<Status> UploadMultipleImagesAsync(string file)
    {
        var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = "xxx",
                ConsumerSecret = "xxx",
                AccessToken = "xxx",
                AccessTokenSecret = "xxx"
            }
        };

        var context = new TwitterContext(auth);

        var additionalOwners = new List<ulong> { 3265644348, 15411837 };
        string status = "Some light humour for my awesome Tweeps. Almost #beeroclock #prost"; 

        var imageUploadTasks =
            new List<Task<Media>> 
            {                    
                context.UploadMediaAsync(File.ReadAllBytes(file), "image/jpg"),
            };

        await Task.WhenAll(imageUploadTasks);

        var mediaIds =
            (from tsk in imageUploadTasks
             select tsk.Result.MediaID)
            .ToList();

        Status tweet = await context.TweetAsync(status, mediaIds);

        if (tweet != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Tweet sent: " + tweet.Text);

        return tweet;            
    }
```

Any help or ideas on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 22nd they do not support tagging through the API

https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-new-photo-tagging-feature/13023/12